# How can you ensure that a user knows they are on your website?

Tags: security, usability

The talk of internet town today is the SNAFU that led to dozens of Facebook users being led by Google search to an article on ReadWriteWeb about the Facebook-AOL deal. What ensued in the [comments tread](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/facebook_wants_to_be_your_one_true_login.php#comment) is quickly becoming the stuff of internet legend.

However, behind the hilarity is a scary fact that this might be how users browse to all sites, including their banking and other more important sites. A quick search for "my bank website login" and quickly click the first result. Once they are there, the user is willing to submit their credentials even though the site looks nothing like the site they tried to reach. (This is evidenced by the fact that user's comments are connected to their facebook accounts via facebook-connect)

Preventing this scenario is pretty much out of our control and educating our users on the basics of internet browsing may be just as impossible. So how then can we ensure that users know they are on the correct web site before trying to log in? Is something like [Bank of America's SiteKey](http://www.bankofamerica.com/privacy/index.cfm?template=sitekey) sufficient, or is that another cop-out that shifts responsibility back on the user?

Comment: "...or is that another cop-out that shifts responsibility back on the user?"  How is that a cop-out?  It **is** the user's responsibility.  If they're willing to type their credentials into any random site, you, as the owner of the legit site, can't stop them.

Comment: meagar, no matter how technologically inept they are, they are still your customers. If you read through the comments on the ReadWriteWeb article you'll see a lot of the frustration and anger these users are expressing is aimed at Facebook who had no control over what was happening! Not facebook's fault, but in the user's eyes the damage is done. I'd argue that you need to at least try to take responsibility for anything that can potentially harm your reputation.

Comment: In your own words, Facebook had no control over the situation.  That was my point.  You can't stop users from incorrectly using the Internet when they're not even reaching your site.

Answer (score 2):

The Internet and web browsers used to have a couple of cool features that might actually have some applicability there.

One was something called "domain names." Instead entering the website name over on the right site of your toolbar, there was another, larger text field on the left where you could enter it. Rather than searching a proprietary Google database running on vast farms of Magic 8-Balls, this arcane "address" field consulted an authoritative registry of "domain names", and would lead you to the right site every time. Sadly, it sometimes required you to enter up to **8** extra characters! This burden was too much for most users to shoulder, and this cumbersome feature has been abandoned.

Another thing you used to see in browsers was something called a "bookmark." Etymologists are still trying to determine where the term "bookmark" originated. They suspect it has something to do with paper with funny squiggles on it. Anyway, these bookmarks allowed users to create a button that would take them directly to the web site of interest. Of course, creating a bookmark was a tedious, intimidating process, sometimes requiring as many as two menu clicks—or worse yet, use of the Ctrl-key!

Ah, the wonders of the ancients.

Comment: "vast farms of Magic 8-Balls" that made me laugh. 
You make me sound ancient with my usage of these arcane arts! Then again, I know better and understand how internet browsing works. It's a new world we live in now though, and the type of user unveiled here are the same people we would hope to have as customers on any internet driven business.

Comment: If "a fool and his money are soon parted," then, yes, these folks look like great customers.

Comment: I blame internet explorer.. What other evil browser do you type in "facebook.com" in the URL address bar only to get a MSN search page saying you searched for "facebook.com".. No no, it requires "http:// facebook.com" to get straight to the site you intend..

Comment: Sure, but those problems aren't made any better by creating a *de facto* meta-standard naming system through search engines.

Comment: people getting confused by search engines has happened for as long as search engines have existed.  removing or hobbling search engines would not siginficantly reduce the problems these people have (and as for the collateral damage...)

Answer (score 1):

When I set up my online bank account, it asked me to choose from a selection of images.  The image I chose is now shown to me every time I login.  This assures me that I am on the right website.

EDIT: i just read the link about the BoA SiteKey, this is apparently the same thing (it sounded from the name like a challenge-response dongle)

I suppose the best answer would be a hardware device which required a code from the bank and the user and authenticated both.  But any of these things assume that people are actually thinking about the problem, which of course they don't.  This was going on before internet banking was common - I had a friend who had her wallet stolen back in the 90s, and theif phoned her pretending to be her bank and persuaded her to reveal her PIN...

Comment: You're assuming someone logging into the site is a savvy user such as yourself, not one that would click on any link from a search result and attempt to login. They may forget they've setup an image and just go with whatever login is presented to them.

Comment: but you only get that once you're logged in right? at which point, the spoof site already has your credentials (or some of them)

Comment: of course, all you can do then is to alert the bank and get your credentials revoked.

Answer (score 1):

The site could "personalize" itself by showing some personal information,
easy recognizable by the user, on every page.
There are plenty of ways to implement it. The obvious one:
under first visit, the site requires user to upload some avatar,
and adds user's id to the cookies. After that, every time the user browses 
the site, the avatar is shown.

Answer (score 0):

When the user first visits the site and logs in, he can share some personal information (even something very trivial) that imposter sites couldn't possible know - high school mascot, first street lived on, etc.

If there's ever any question of site authenticity, the site could share this information back to the user.

Like on TV shows/movies with the evil twin.  The good twin always wins trust by sharing a secret that only the person who's trying to figure out who the good twin is would know.

Comment: If you read the comments on the linked website you would realize how much that is asking of these people. If the image wasn't shown they wouldn't think something was wrong - they would likely think that the bank had come up with some new routine to make things less of a bother for them.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't provide the security you think it does. Just look at the example of Sarah Palin's "hacked" account.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent phishing per-se but you can take several steps each of which do a little bit to mitigate the problem.

1) If you have something like site-key or a sign-in seal, please ensure that these cannot be iframed on a malicious website. Just javascript framebusting may not be enough as IE has security="restricted".

2) Be very consistent about how you ask for user credentials - serve the login form over SSL (not just post-back over SSL). Do not ask for login on several places or sites. Encourage third parties who want to work with user data stored on your site to use OAuth (instead of taking your user's password).

3) You should never ask for information via email (with or without link).

4) Have a security page where you talk about these issues.

5) Send notification on changes to registered phone, email, etc.

Apart from above, monitor user account activity - such as changes to contact information, security Q&A, access, etc (noting time, ip, and there are several subtle techniques).